# EX editor: go to previous file

Tags: vi, ex

Using `ex` I open 3 files

```
ex file1 file2 file3
```

I know

- the command `:n` goes to file 2 and file3
- the command `:rew` go to file1 from file3 or file2

But what command can I use to go to previous file?
I think `:e previousfile` will work, but does something
quicker like `:n` for previous exist?

Comment: `vim` has `:p` but for `vi` the best I can offer is `:e#`

Comment: I think `:N` works in `vi`.

Comment: In vi probably on ex no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [POSIX specifications for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

> Implementations wanting to provide a counterpart to the **next** command that edited the previous file have used the command **prev[ious]**, which takes no *file* argument. POSIX.1-2008 does not require this command.

So, in *most* implementations, **`:prev` will do what you want.**  (That is, most implementations of `ex` that *I've* encountered; obviously you shouldn't rely on this for portable scripting.)

Note also that this is *not* the same as `:p`, which actually means to `p`rint the current line.  `prev` is the shortest abbreviation allowed.  (`pre` means "preserve".)